# python load file content with no context manager

Tags: python, file, iterator

I do this:

```
f = open('foo.txt', 'rb')
ii = (x for x in f.readlines())
f.close()

print(next(ii))
```

I see problem in my implementation of this code with use of iterator and calling `next` after file is closed.

Is this implementation not problematic due to a fact of using iterator and executing on iterator after the file is closed regardless of no use of context manager?

Comment: The same behaviour would be achieved using `with open('foo.txt', 'rb') as f: ii = (x for x in f.readlines());print(next(ii))`

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't, because `f.readlines()` is evaluated when the generator expression is created:

```
f = open('foo.txt', 'rb')
ii = (x for x in f.readlines())
print(f.tell()) # nonzero for non-empty file (shows how far we read)
f.close()
```

Note that, although we never call `next`, the file's content has already been loaded.